# VB 2010 sendkeys ERROR

Tags: vb.net, sendkeys

I use VB for the first time. I dont know, why this easy code does not work.

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button2_Click_1(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Application.Exit()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
        Dim ProcID As Integer
        ProcID = 2940
        AppActivate(ProcID)
        SendKeys.SendWait("Username")
        SendKeys.SendWait("{ENTER}")
        SendKeys.SendWait("Password")
        SendKeys.SendWait("{ENTER}")
    End Sub
End Class
```

Error:
[image]

Comment: In which line does this exception appear?

Comment: the first SendKeys line

Comment: Have you tries My.Computer.Keyboard.SendKey ?

Comment: yes, same error..
Do i need to import something ?

Comment: If you deleted the `AppActivate()` function, will it still give you this error?

Comment: This work, but they send it nowere, so do you think, that my Programm does have some protections against sendkeys ? or there is generelly something like this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because of Game Guard is protectiong my Window....
"Just" do Bypass and its done =)